# How to downsize an array by removing duplicates and assign new string value based on key value difference?

Tags: php, arrays

There is this array where it presents a list of restaurants for a searched food name it needs to be downsized to unique results.
This array as you can see can contain duplicate restaurant names the key factor is the preparation time the array needs to assign a string with a value of "multi-options" if the restaurant names match but the preparation time is different.

**The array:**

```
$restaurants = array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 15,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 10,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 20,
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 5,
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Alto Burger',
    'slug' => 'alto-burger',
    'lat' => 45.487302399999997,
    'long' => -73.637301199999996,
    'distance' => '3.04',
    'preparation' => 10,
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Alto Burger',
    'slug' => 'alto-burger',
    'lat' => 45.487302399999997,
    'long' => -73.637301199999996,
    'distance' => '3.04',
    'preparation' => 10,
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Subway',
    'slug' => 'subway1',
    'lat' => 45.268204699999998,
    'long' => -72.143240399999996,
    'distance' => '71.29',
    'preparation' => 3,
  ),
)
```

This array presents :

1. **Chefoncall** (that has different preparation time values) and needs to present one array with preparation value of "multi-option".
2. **Alto Burger** (that has 2 arrays but same preparation time of 10) and needs to present one array with the preparation time of 10.
3. **Subway** (this has one array and a preparation time of 3) and it needs to present as it is no need to alter this.

**The required output**

```
  $restaurantsdownsized = array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 'multi-option',
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Alto Burger',
    'slug' => 'alto-burger',
    'lat' => 45.487302399999997,
    'long' => -73.637301199999996,
    'distance' => '3.04',
    'preparation' => 10,
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Subway',
    'slug' => 'subway1',
    'lat' => 45.268204699999998,
    'long' => -72.143240399999996,
    'distance' => '71.29',
    'preparation' => 3,
  ),
)
```

Then it needs to generate the following div elements so it can be added as a marker to a google map.

```
    foreach($restaurantsdownsized as $mp){  
        echo '<div class="radarmarkers" 
                data-lat="'.$mp['lat'].'" 
                data-long="'.$mp['long'].'" 
                data-title="'.$mp['restaurant'].'"
                data-preparation= "'.$mp['preparation'].' '.t('Minutes').'"
                data-map-icon= "icon_'.$mp['preparation'].'"
                ></div>';
    }
```

Comment: Would it be correct to say that if slug is equal and preparation is not equal to eachother then it should be multi-option? Or what is slug? Is it restaurant number as I think?

Comment: @Andreas, that would be correct also. slug and restaurant name can be the index key for matching. slug is for generating SEO friendly urls. like url.com/restaurant/slug...

Comment: do you need to save indexes - 1,14,15 ?

Comment: @splash58 no i just need the $restaurantsdownsized. it can be 1,2,3

Comment: Sorry don't have time to do more. Have a one week old baby that needs my attention more than you do. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6b67877609ec049033a57faa8dd3af0cede94398

Comment: @Andreas, Please attend to your baby. :)

Comment: My plan was to use $newres as the new array with the copied values from the original array and just replace prep time if needed.

Comment: @Andreas Would this be correct? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8170238bfbc67786b86d7a056ec78e07a2a1bb09

Comment: @codedudey nice! I probably would have ended up with something like it. You will get an upvote from me :-)

Comment: @Andreas, Your code give me this idea so yeah :), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if i can answer my own question but here is a solution that i came up with:

```
$temprestaurants = $restaurants;
if(count($restaurants) > 1){
        $range  = range(1, count($restaurants));

        foreach($restaurants as $key => $value ){
            foreach($range as $x){
                if($value['slug']==$temprestaurants[$x]['slug']){
                    if($temprestaurants[$x]['preparation']!= $value['preparation']){
                        $temprestaurants[$x]['preparation'] = "multi-option";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
$restaurantsdownsized = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize",$temprestaurants)));
var_dump($restaurantsdownsized);
```

**It produces the desired output**

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["restaurant"]=>
    string(10) "Chefoncall"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(11) "chefoncall1"
    ["lat"]=>
    float(45.4958692)
    ["long"]=>
    float(-73.575247)
    ["distance"]=>
    string(4) "0.07"
    ["preparation"]=>
    string(12) "multi-option"
  }
  [13]=>
  array(6) {
    ["restaurant"]=>
    string(11) "Alto Burger"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(11) "alto-burger"
    ["lat"]=>
    float(45.4873024)
    ["long"]=>
    float(-73.6373012)
    ["distance"]=>
    string(4) "3.04"
    ["preparation"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [15]=>
  array(6) {
    ["restaurant"]=>
    string(6) "Subway"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(7) "subway1"
    ["lat"]=>
    float(45.2682047)
    ["long"]=>
    float(-72.1432404)
    ["distance"]=>
    string(5) "71.29"
    ["preparation"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can. And in two days I believe you can accept it too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) {
$temp_array = array();
$i = 0;
$key_array = array();

foreach($array as $val) {
    if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
        $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
        $temp_array[$i] = $val;
    }
    $i++;
}
return $temp_array;
```

}

```
$restaurants = array (
```

`1 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 15,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 10,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 20,
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 5,
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Chefoncall',
    'slug' => 'chefoncall1',
    'lat' => 45.495869200000001,
    'long' => -73.57524699999999,
    'distance' => '0.07',
    'preparation' => 0,
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Alto Burger',
    'slug' => 'alto-burger',
    'lat' => 45.487302399999997,
    'long' => -73.637301199999996,
    'distance' => '3.04',
    'preparation' => 10,
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Alto Burger',
    'slug' => 'alto-burger',
    'lat' => 45.487302399999997,
    'long' => -73.637301199999996,
    'distance' => '3.04',
    'preparation' => 10,
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    'restaurant' => 'Subway',
    'slug' => 'subway1',
    'lat' => 45.268204699999998,
    'long' => -72.143240399999996,
    'distance' => '71.29',
    'preparation' => 3,
  ),
);
$restaurants = unique_multidim_array($restaurants,'preparation');
var_dump($restaurants);`

As I see it you can get either unique restaurant or unique preparation time.

Comment: :). that is the tricky part it needs to represent unique restaurants and modify the preparation time if differs and assign a new value of "multi-option" to it.

Comment: There's $unique = array_unique($restaurants, SORT_REGULAR); too.

Comment: the whole point of this was to modify the preparation time of similar times if the preparation time would differ. check my answer.

Comment: `$key='restaurant';
$restaurants1 = unique_multidim_array($restaurants,$key);

$array=array();
foreach($restaurants1 as $key => $value)
{
   $string=$value['restaurant'];$$value['restaurant']=array();$i=1;
   foreach($restaurants as $keys=>$values)
   {
  if($values['restaurant']===$string){
     array_push($$value['restaurant'],$restaurants[$i]);
  }
  $i++;
 }
 
   array_push($array,unique_multidim_array($$value['restaurant'],'preparation'));
   
}`

Comment: foreach($array as $key => $value){
 foreach($value as $key => $values){
  if(count($value)>1){
   $values['preparation']='multi-option</br>';
  }
  foreach($values as $key => $values){
   
   echo $values."</br>";
  }
 }
 echo "</br>";
}  I was thinking that different preparations probably weren't duplicates.

Comment: As long as the restaurant name is the same and preparation time is different they are duplicates.